# Is it possible to call some code on viewDidAppear without using inheritance

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

My app project utilizes some third-party lib which exposes a view controller class (`LibViewController`). This class is defined as `final public`, so I cannot inherit from it.

I need to run some code when this controller appears. Normally, I would override `viewDidAppear`, but as I told, I cannot use inheritance.

Is there any way to be notified when the view controller appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  self.present(LibViewController(), animated: true) {

        // your code after LibViewController is shown

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use swift, try

```
extension LibViewController {
    override public func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
    }
}
```

In this way you got superclass's method, this will not work, if viewDidAppear is used in LibViewController class